# Should I use "won't", "wouldn't" or "shouldn't" in the following conditional sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> If planets are falling on Earth tomorrow, they **won't/wouldn't/shouldn't** look as
>   small as a star (today)."

The "[if X are doing Y tomorrow...they won't](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&q=%22if%20you%20*%20again%20tomorrow%20*%20won%27t%22&oq=%22if%20you%20*%20again%20tomorrow%20*%20won%27t%22&gs_l=serp.3...1195.1893.0.1990.5.5.0.0.0.0.151.387.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..4.1.149._HPFXaIMEx0)" construction has the most results on Google, so I'm leaning towards *won't*. Still, I'm not very sure ... is this the correct option? Why?

Comment: I think, since in if clause you are using present participle, wont is more logical. (If I had to select one of them, It will be "wont")

Comment: @Cardinal, "If I had to select one of them, it ***would*** be won't".  Practice what you preach.

Comment: @VictorBazarov :) At the moment, I feel I'm a stupid learner! However, my intent was , "If I have to ..." thanks BTW

Answer (score 1):

*First conditional*, the "***if***" is in *present tense* (in fact, it's *past-in-future*), the main clause needs to be in the respective tense, here (since you talk about "tomorrow") *future indefinite*.  You could use "are going to" since it's near future.

> If planets *are* falling on Earth tomorrow, they **won't** look as small as a star (today).
>   If planets *are* falling on Earth tomorrow, they **aren't going to** look as small as a star (today).

*Second conditional*, the "if" is in past tense (expressing less likely scenario), the main clause has "would"

> If planets *were* falling on Earth tomorrow, they **wouldn't** look as small as a star (today).

*Third conditional* here is impossible since only *first* and *second* conditionals are used when talking of the *future*.